# RESTful client API for uCLib

Tags: rest, embedded, uclibc

I need to implement a RESTfull client in an embedded environnement using uClibc.

Is there any open source library that implements RESTful Client in C that could only rely on µClibc?

Answer (score 0):

REST is an architectural pattern. It is a collection of constraint's on your system, in order for your system to have a particular set of properties.

The constraints are;

- client-server - A separation of concerns.
- stateless - Every request to the server must be a complete and understandable request.
- cache-able - Every request's results should be cache-able (if the same request is repeated).
- layered - No component must know about or understand another component in another layer.
- uniform interface - simplifies and decouples the architecture.
- code-on-demand - (optional) Allow extensions to be transmitted and executed on the client.

The Properties to your system are;

- Scalability of component interactions
- Generality of interfaces
- Independent deployment of components
- Intermediary components to reduce latency, enforce security and encapsulate legacy systems
  (From REST wiki page)

There is nothing here to do with how you implement REST. REST can occur over any transport layer that provides mechanisms for the constraints.